# How can I boot Linux with too many logical volumes?

Tags: linux, mbr, overflow

I've created 45 logical volumes (and one extended) with fdisk on a non-boot HDD.

Now the system refuses to boot, as well as any Linux live CD, that I've tried. Computer always turns off just after starting loading kernel (when loader output is cleared and no kernel info appears on screen).

Where does this limitation come from? What should I do to load any system and fill the MBR with zeros?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where the limit comes from...

As for clearing the disk:

- DBAN might just do it because it doesn't try to read the old content of the fdisk.
- Good old MS-DOS fdisk might just be dumb enough that it would work. (Or DR-DOS, or FreeDOS)
- If it is SATA try to boot from a IDE device, with the SATA controller excluded from the boot-device list. Vice versa if it is IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is turning off just after loading the Kernel, whether from hard drive, or from CD, then you have a physical heat issue with your CPU.

I'm willing to bet you just added a new drive since you stated that this is a non-boot hdd. This new drive is generating enough heat to cause your system to power off.

There is no limitation of logical volumes you can have.

Comment: Could be the cause. But just adding 1 extra disk usually doesn't add that much heat, especially on a cold-start. PSU overload when the disk spins up seems more likely...

Comment: the HDD is not new to system, it was here for years. There is no device was made recently, only stupid testing for mbr handling